# How to automatic spelling correction in command line

Tags: command-line, spell-checking

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10.

I wonder if there is some app, or some command to get automatic spelling correction when we use command line (Terminal session).

Some idea?

Comment: you can generally use `TAB` to auto-complete directories, file names, and several commands

Comment: many commands such as `sed`, `printf`, `ls` and `grep` would fail spell checking. They are abbreviations. For example: `grep` abbreviates from  **g**lobally search a **r**egular **e**xpression and **p**rint.

Comment: If you use the same commands often, the shell 'fish' will remember and auto complete them for you.  Find it easier to use than 'bash' shell's tab.